# create a debian installer with custom kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel

First what I need to do is install a debian on a [3300mx computer](http://www.compactpc.com.tw/ebox-3300MX.htm) which is based on a vortex cpu. 
The problem is the debian installer always crash because the required drivers are in the kernel as modules only.
So I tried to create a custom kernel with the required drivers as native instead of modules.
After a few attemps I managed to get 3 files:

> - linux-headers-3.0.0_0.2_i386.deb
> - linux-image-3.0.0_0.2_i386.deb
> - linux-libc-dev_0.2_i386.deb

I'm not even sure that I compiled these files the right way. I tried to follow some tutorials that asked me to compile my kernel with the command line :

> $>fakeroot make-kpkg --append-to-version "-custom" --revision "0.1" --us --uc --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers

The problem is that when I do that, I've got the following output:

> - /usr/bin/make  EXTRAVERSION=-boxls  ARCH=i386 -C Documentation/lguest
> - make: *** Documentation/lguest: No such file or directory.  Stop.
> - make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2

To get the 3 .deb files I had to use a simpler command line without all the params like --append-to-version so I'm not sure they are good.
Once I'll be sure my .deb files are ok I need to create a custom tftp debian installer to try it on the computers. I'm lost because I can't find out what to do with my .deb files as all the tutorials ends with a simple installation on the current system instead of the creation of a custom debian installer...
Can you help me please?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Creating an own installer would probably be overkill in your situation. If you need it only once, then all you need is to use `debootstrap` from a LiveCD (that supports your system). The complete guide is presented here: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/426
And in the comments you even see how to include your custom kernel.